# How do you manage installation of paid modules with composer?

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace

We are using a popular magento module for payment gateway and when we wanted to install it on a magento2 project we received the module as a zip file.

When I asked about a composer package they replied that being a paid module you cannot install it via composer.

Is there no way to manage paid modules via composer in magento2 marketplace?

Comment: You can install via Setup Wizard or Composer _any_ extension you get from Magento Marketplace. I have tried only free extensions but paid extensions work the same way. Unfortunately, the process for Composer installation is difficult right now because the only place the Composer name displays is on the invoice (it's the SKU). If you'd like more information, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no way to manage paid modules via composer ?

Yes , Handling private packages with Satis or Toran Proxy [Here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md)

Magento 2 [marketplace](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-2) has extension list , but when we click on the extensions those are redirecting to related extension pages, you know Magento 1.x also does the same process for Paid extension. I mean to say they are not maintaining the source code.

> replied that being a paid module you cannot install it via composer.

Providing code for paid or purchased license extensions is up to there choice. we can go with composer private packages to install Megento 2 extensions if we have.
Hope this helps ..:)